# Nuxt - Passing Relative Path as Prop results in 404

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an array of json objects that I'm importing in a page.  I am iterating through the data and passing the objects to a component as a prop.  One attribute of the json data on the objects is a relative path for an img (currently in my /assets/ folder).

ex. json

```js
[
    {
        "title":"val1",
        "img": "~/assets/image1.jpg",
        "text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"

    },
    {
        "title": "val2",
        "img": "~/assets/image2.jpg",
        "text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"

    },
    {
        "title": "val3",
        "img": "~/assets/image3.jpg",
        "text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
 
    }
]
```

The component of the vue library I'm using (bootstrap-vue) has an "img-src" directive that can take a url or path to an image to display. When I pass the prop to this directive, I'm getting a malformed path to the image and a 404.

ex. usage

```html
<div>
    <b-card :img-src="data.img"></b-card>
</div>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        data: {
            title: String,
            img: String,
            text: String
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The resulting request url for the asset looks like http://localhost:3000/~/assets/image1.jpg.  If I simply pass a static string path to the directive

```html
<div>
    <b-card img-src="~/assets/image1.jpg"></b-card>
</div>
```

The image loads as expected and the url for the asset looks like http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/assets/image1.jpg

Can anyone explain what's going wrong here?

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65869284/8172857

Comment: try `<b-card :img-src="data.img" v-if="data.img"></b-card>` and see if it gets fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Props declaration

Your props aren't declared correctly. You can declare a `data` prop as an `Object`, or individual props for `title`, `img`, and `text`.  I think you meant to declare them individually:

```js
export default {
    props: {
        //data: {
        //    title: String,
        //    img: String,
        //    text: String
        //}

        title: String,
        img: String,
        text: String
    }
}
```

#### Asset URL Handling

Nuxt uses `vue-loader` to load Vue SFCs, and `vue-loader` [automatically transforms asset URLs into Webpack module requests via `require`](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html#transform-rules), and this is only done for literal values (not for dynamic values bound by `v-bind`). This asset URL transformation applies to a subset of tags and attributes (including `<img>.src`), but that can be configured via its [`transformAssetUrls` option](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/options.html#transformasseturls).

`bootstrap-vue`'s Nuxt plugin [configures `transformAssetUrls` to include `<b-card>.imgSrc`](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/b2325a3/nuxt/index.js#L79), which is why `<b-card img-src="~/assets/image1.jpg">` works without any special treatment.

Since you have dynamic `img-src` URLs, they need to be `require`d:

```html
<template>
  <b-card :img-src="computedImg"></b-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  //...
  computed: {
    computedImg() {
      // Workaround `require` issue by prefixing `~/assets`
      // https://stackoverflow.com/q/60569609/6277151
      return require('~/assets/' + this.img.replace(/^~\/assets\//g, ''))
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-bootstrap-vue-dynamic-img?file=components%2FCard.vue)

Comment: The actual name of the object I'm passing as a prop is "post," not "data."  Sorry if that caused confusion with keywords.  The actual data is indeed being passed to the component just fine (e.g title, text, the img url output in curly braces), and I had assumed my format was just a type-safe way of passing an object as a prop.  If there's a better way of accomplishing that, please let me know.  I had tried using require before (having seen that documentation), but didn't realize I'd have to sanitize the path.  That workaround solved it; thanks.

Comment: As a side note, using ````require('~/assets/' + ...)```` here is causing webpack to throw a couple of (seemingly unrelated) warnings for unexpected tokens.  ./assets/Readme.md - "Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)" and ./assets/fonts/OFL.txt - "Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:10)".  Do I need an additional loader here?

Comment: Ok. The incorrect prop declaration won't prevent the prop from being passed to the component, but Vue won't provide any type checks. The invalid prop declaration effectively tells Vue to accept anything. See [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-invalid-prop-decl?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)

Comment: For the `require` behavior: [Webpack parses dynamic `require` expressions](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression), and creates a context for the static part of the expression, evalulating all files within the context. In this example, the context is `~/assets`, so it reads all files there, including the `README.md`, leading to the error. To address that, move your image assets into a subdirectory (e.g., `~/assets/img`), and update the `require` expression's static part along with the URLs from your JSON to match.